# How to get split editor strings into a ListView on a different page on a Xamarin App?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, split, editor

I have an editor that collects names through user input. I ask the user to put in every name separated by commas. Now I want all the names to appear as Text cells on a different page.

Unfortunately, the 'Completed' method makes it only accessible in a private void

In the following, "text2" is the whole user input that gets split up into the string array "girlsSplit[]"

The button at the end redirects the user to the page where all the names are supposed to be displayed in a ListView. I need to transform the string[] girlsSplit to this page, but I cannot access it.
As you can tell I am a very beginner at programming.

```
private void NamesGirls_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var text2 = ((Editor)sender).Text; 
        string[] girlsSplit = text2.Split(','); 


    }


    private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        await Navigation.PushAsync(new Wuensche());

    }
```

I would highly appreciate workaround solutions because I don't like my coding here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare `girlsSplit` as a class level variable, not a local variable, and then pass it via the constructor to your next page

```
string[] girlsSplit;

private void NamesGirls_Completed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var text2 = ((Editor)sender).Text; 
    girlsSplit = text2.Split(','); 
}

private async void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    await Navigation.PushAsync(new Wuensche(girlsSplit));
}
```

you will also need to add a constructor that accepts a string[]

```
string[] _girls;

public Wuensche(string girls) {
  _girls = girls;
}
```

Comment: Alright, but now I get an error message, that Wuensche() does not contain a constructor that takes 2 arguments

Comment: you need to add a constructor to Wuensche that accepts a string[] parameter

Comment: You are saving my life. Since it still fits my question and you seem really competent, do you know how I can now turn this string[] into cells of a ListView?

Comment: the docs include an example that does exactly that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding